# CompleteableFuture in a loop contruct in a private Ethereum Blockchain

Tags: java, concurrency, blockchain, ethereum

I have a private Ethereum blockchain set up with 5 machines mining on it. The size of the block chain [number of blocks] are as of now, 300. The processing is done on back-end Java.

I need to run the following loop construct in a asynchronous manner. The bottleneck of the loop is during the execution of the following command:

> `EthBlock eb = web3.ethGetBlockByNumber(new DefaultBlockParameterNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(i)), true).send();`

The command can also return a `Completablefuture<EthBlock>` object by ending it with `supplyAsync()` given here https://github.com/web3j/web3j#start-sending-requests Just calling `supplyAync().get()` removes the parallelism aspect and makes it behave synchronously.

```
public void businessLogic() throws Exception {
        recentBlocks = new ArrayList<EthBlock.Block>();
        for (long i = 1; i <= 300000; i++) {
            EthBlock eb = web3.ethGetBlockByNumber(new DefaultBlockParameterNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(i)), true).send();
            if (eb == null || eb.getBlock() == null) {
                continue;
            }
            EthBlock.Block block = eb.getBlock();
            recentBlocks.add(block);
        }
    }
```

I not able to grasp the institution of translating the code into a way CompleteableFuture can operate on. Goal is to 'group' up multiple calls to `web.ethGetBlockNumber(...).supplyAync()` into a collection and call them all at once to update an array which will get filled by `EthBlock` objects i.e `recentBlocks`.

This is what I came up with:

```
public void businessLogic() throws Exception {
    recentBlocks = new ArrayList<EthBlock.Block>();
    List<CompleteableFuture> compFutures = new ArrayList<>();
    for (long i = 0, i <= 300000, i++){
        CompleteableFuture<EthBlock> compFuture = eb3.ethGetBlockByNumber(new DefaultBlockParameterNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(i)), true).sendAsync();
        compFuture.thenAcceptAsync(eb -> // Doesn't look right
        EthBlock.Block block = eb.getBlock();
        recentBlock.add(block);)
        compFutures.add(compFuture);        
    }
    CompleteableFuture.allOf(compFutures).get();
}
```

---

**Implementing IntStream**

```
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    recentBlocks = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 300_000)
             .parallel()
             .mapToObj(i -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Current Thread -> " + Thread.currentThread());
                    return web3.ethGetBlockByNumber(new DefaultBlockParameterNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(i)), true).send();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            })
             .filter(Objects::nonNull)
             .map(EthBlock::getBlock)
             .filter(Objects::nonNull)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
    long stop = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Time Elapsed: " + TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.convert(stop-start, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to benefit from a parallel stream instead of relying on `CompletableFuture`, assuming the order of the resulting `List` isn't important:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 300_000)
         .parallel()
         .mapToObj(i -> web3.ethGetBlockByNumber(new DefaultBlockParameterNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(i)), true).send())
         .filter(Objects::nonNull)
         .map(EthBlock::getBlock)
         .filter(Objects::nonNull)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Because you stated that didn't help, let's try an `ExecutorService` that utilizes a cached thread pool instead:

```
List<EthBlock.Block> blocks = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>(300_000));

ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

for (int i = 0; i <= 300_000; i++) {
    BigInteger number = BigInteger.valueOf(i);

    service.execute(() -> {
        EthBlock eb = web3.ethGetBlockByNumber(new DefaultBlockParameterNumber(number), true).send();

        if (eb == null) {
            return;
        }

        EthBlock.Block block = eb.getBlock();

        if (block != null) {
            blocks.add(block);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I ran your code and did some bench marked it to compare it with simple for loop code. Oddly, it did not give me any performance gain, both techniques are take 11 seconds to go through 50 iteration [partial range of 300_000]. In my `Thread.currentThread()`, it prints `[http-nio-8080-exec-54,5,main]` for every *IntStream* instance [given in the `maptoObj`. Is there a way to force it to instantiate maximum number of threads available to retrieve the object?

Comment: @user280930 See the edit I posted just now; hopefully that should help.

Comment: Thanks! The new code is performing asynchronous and is much faster than the previous one. `Executors...` finishes the 50 calls 0.4 seconds, huge improvement from 11 seconds. Strangely, when I ran the `IntStream` method, it's also now working asynchronously and `System.currentThread()` is prints out `ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main` [unique]. I have no idea why it's all of a sudden running async. Would love to know why. It's also not as fast as it completes execution in 1.4 sec. Lastly, do you know why I can work with `web3.eth..sendAsync` that returns `CompletableFuture<EthBlock>` ?

Comment: I believe the `IntStream` solution only uses some finite amount of threads whereas the `ExecutorService` solution uses one thread per task (and caches them for re-use).  I don’t know what you’re asking about why you can work with `CompletableFuture` though.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I meant to ask `web3j` provide an *implementation* of async as given [here](https://github.com/web3j/web3j#start-sending-requests). Instead of using `web3.eth...send()`, I can use it's async method to return a `CompletableFuture<EthBlock>` object. From the code you gave me, it works and it's fast but it totally ignores the *async* implementation provided by the library. Isn't there any possibility to use it to perform the exactly the same task given above?

Comment: Probably, but I'm not familiar enough with `CompletableFuture` to help in that area.

Answer (score 1):

CompletableFuture contains an Override for get:
`get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`. You can use this to poll by making the get timeout if it does not return within a specific time.

Comment: I gave the timeout to one minute `EthBlock eb = web3.ethGetBlockByNumber(new DefaultBlockParameterNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(i)), true).sendAsync().get(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
` but it doesn't run asynchronously. Running `System.out.println("Thread.currentThread())';` in the loop prints out -> `Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-10,5,main]`, over and over again.

Comment: Giving a timeout will not cause it run asynchronously, you will have to implement that feature, by giving a small timeout, like 1 second. And coming back to try again later if it times out. Understand?

Comment: Yes, using the `timeout` will allow me to get a result back at least by allowing it a grace period to return a result. But I need have multiple instance/thread of the `eth.ethGetBlockNumber` to take advantage of each returning a result some later in time. Doing it one by one is too slow.